# Safari IOS Fails to open PkPass but Mac Safari opens

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, passbook

Safari IOS fails to download the pkpass howerver mac safari opens it successfully, 
I get the following error...

Sample can be found here.. http://home.shortkut.co/api/public/PassbookCoupon.pkpass/
I am also passing the correct content-type. 
Content-Type: application/vnd.apple.pkpass
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=pass.pkpass

My pass.json looks the following...

```
 {
    "passTypeIdentifier":"pass.co.shortkut.home",
    "formatVersion":1,
    "serialNumber":"01927847623423234234",
    "description":"Shalimar 20 Coupon",
    "organizationName":"Shortkut.co",
    "teamIdentifier":"*******",
    "logoText":"Home.Shortkut.co",
    "foregroundColor":"rgb(255,255,255)",
     "backgroundColor":"rgb(0,0,0)",
     "coupon":
         {"headerFields":[],
          "primaryFields":[{"key":"discount","label":"Discount","numberStyle":"PKNumberStylePercent","value":0.01}],
          "secondaryFields":[],
          "auxiliaryFields":[],
          "backFields":[]},
          "barcode":   {"format":"PKBarcodeFormatPDF417","message":"01927847623423234234","messageEncoding":"UTF-8","altText":"01927847623423234234"}
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Updated : Url: http://home.shortkut.co/api/public/PassbookCoupon.pkpass/

Comment: If I click on your link I get `The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`.  This error is nearly always due to the certificate or signing.  Without a pass link, I can't tell you much more than that.

Comment: Updated the Url, its had a typo at the end http://home.shortkut.co/api/public/PassbookCoupon.pkpass/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your .pkpass bundle does not contain an icon.

```
Apr 27 15:36:51 iPhone Chrome[620] <Warning>: Invalid data error reading pass pass.co.shortkut.home/01927847623423234234. Pass does not contain icon.png/icon@2x.png/icon@3x.png
```

Add an icon.png image to the bundle and you should be ok.

Comment: that worked, what tool didn't you use to debug that?

Comment: Xcode. Hook up your phone and monitor the console output in the devices window.

Comment: And if you don't have a mac, what are the alternative? Can I get those logs on mobile safari?

Comment: Then you're screwed! You want to develop for iOS then you need a Mac. Cheap alternative would be to virtualise one on your Windows/Linux box.

Comment: Is this same as using web inspector? or are there instructions to do this from xcode, I can't get xcode show me the errors.

Comment: Not the same as web inspector.  Open Xcode, click Window -> Devices, then click on your device in the left hand bar.  The console log is on the bottom of the right hand pane.  If you don't see anything then click the up arrow in the bottom left corner of the right pane.